# Тройной вызов контроллера при старте веб приложения

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Добрый день. Пишу веб приложение. На бэкенде spring mvc со следующей конфигурацией:

```
public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    ctx.register(WebApp.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME,
            new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
}
```

}

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ua"})
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({StorageConfig.class})
public class WebApp extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/presentation/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/presentation/**").addResourceLocations("/presentation/");
}
```

}

Так же есть стандартный контроллер, который замаплен на "/":

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    System.out.println("Hello\n");
    return "redirect:/records";
}
```

}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/records", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView records() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("records",  recordService.getByUserLogin(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()));
    model.addObject("currentUser", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
    model.setViewName("records");
    return model;
}
```

Во время запуска томкета, почему-то этот этот конроллер запускается 3 раза (3 раза в консоли появляется надпись Hello). Не могу понять, почему это происходит. Кто знает в чем причина, объясните пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что у вас находится по адресу "/records" ?

Comment: @aleksandr gaiduchok, по этому адресу контроллер, который перенаправляет на вьюшку. Добавил в первый пост. Но честно говоря, это не важно что в этом контроллере, даже если контроллер, который замаплен на /, будет просто перенаправлять на вьюшку, эффект один и тот же.

Comment: Мне кажется в таких случаях, желательно свой проект размещать на github'е, что бы можно было детально все посмотреть и возможно скомпилировать у себя для отладки.

Comment: @ЕвгенийТупиков, Весь проект -  https://github.com/YSSerious/Lardi_Test. Контроллеры немого расширились, но суть одна и та же.

Answer (score 2):

Метод контролера может вызвать трижды при использовании Intellij IDEA(когда приложение стартует) - потому что включена конфигурация сервера "After launch".

Попробуй отменить выбор "Run/Debug Configuration"->левое меню "Tomcat"-> вкладка "Server" -> галка "After launch"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: это не решение проблемы, это оттягивание, при обновлении страницы, подобная проблема появляется снова.

Comment: Stanislav Progrosyan, может у вас есть какой-то вариант решения?

Comment: Как я понял, это проблема логики архитектуры самого приложения. У меня проблема была, что я в лист через метод добавлял данные. После каждого обновления страницы, количество данных в листе увеличивались. Соответственно, при каждом вызове метода `public String home()` (а sping и idea его вызывают дополнительно) появляются данные, или как в самом вопросе, вывод в консоль.

Comment: Товарищ Mkyong у себя на https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-beans-loaded-twice/ сайте рассказывает почему может быть двойной вызов